# Bootstrap dropdown - open from span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

See [here](http://www.bootply.com/L2RpDwcOwM):
 (thanks to I Can Has Kittenz for this)

**Code**

```
//Initially the need size should be shown
var need_size=true;
//when the cursor enters the button area
$('#cart-btn').mouseenter(function(){
 //we check if the message needs to be shown
 if(need_size==true){
    //if yes, show it
    $(this).find('span').html('NEED SIZE');
  }
});
$('#cart-btn').mouseleave(function(){
    //when the cursor leaves the button, we restore back the text
    $(this).find('span').html('ADD TO CART');
});

$(".dropdown-menu li label").click(function(){
  var selected = $(this).text();
  $(this).parents('#cart-dd').find('.dropdown-toggle').html(selected);
  //we disable the need size text to be shown once an option is selected
  need_size=false;
});
```

How would I open the dropdown if a user was to click the button when the span "NEED SIZE" message was showing. Here is incorrect code example of what I mean:

```
 if(need_size==true){
    //if yes, show it
    $(this).find('span').html('NEED SIZE').click('span').find('.dropdown-toggle').addClass('open');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

as of the bootstrap [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns)

```
$().dropdown('toggle')
```

> Toggles the dropdown menu of a given navbar or tabbed navigation.

so use to to show / hide the dropdown, for example during the mouseenter event you declared

```
if(need_size==true){
    $(".cart-dd.dropdown-toggle").dropdown("toggle");
}
```

Comment: thanks! how would get this to work on click instead of on mouseover?

Comment: change mouseover to click, or move the statement from mouseover handler to click handler :)